# Unable to create JIRA plugin - getting error "Unable to execute mojo: archive is not a ZIP archive"

Tags: plugins, jira

After installing the latest *Atlassian JIRA SDK* on Windows, I try to run the first tutorial but I'm getting a `BUILD FAILURE`.

This all works fine on Mac OS High Sierra (of course), but not Windows.

I am using the following environment:

```
Windows Server 2008 R2
Java 1.8.192
JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152
```

I am trying to create the example plugin.
https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/getting-started/getting-started-with-plugins2

I am following the tutorial's instructions, and not modifying anything. I

- downloaded sdk-installer-6.2.15.exe and installed.
- created a directory, C:\JIRA and cd'd to it.
- ran the command **atlas-create-jira-plugin**
- filled in prompts following the tutorial.
- ran **atlas-run**

I get the error:

```
BUILD FAILURE
Failed to execute goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-dispatcher-plugin:6.2.11:run (default-cli) on project myPlugin: Unable to execute mojo: archive is not a ZIP archive
```

Comment: Before atlas-run make sure you are in the directory created for your plugin